# UseEffect still runs even if fetch data doesnt change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

i have this UseEffect() code and even if i pass the 2nd paramenter it just keeps re-rendering even if the data doesn't change, Any idea? hope to get a solution soon (MERN)

FRONTEND

```
const [qty, setQty] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/QtyCheck',{
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(qtyValue=>{
        setQty(qtyValue)
    })
},[qty])enter code here
```

BACKEND

```
    router.get('/QtyCheck',(req,res)=>{
    Post.find({},{qty:1,minT:1,criT:1, code:1,name:1,isDisable:1})
    .then(postFind=>{
        if(postFind.length===0){
            res.json("nil")
        }else{
           res.json(postFind)
        }
    }).catch(noPost=>{
        res.json("Error",noPost)
    })
})
```

Comment: You are setting ```qty``` inside your useEffect, which causing it to call it again

Comment: @szczocik, Yes that was the intention, qty changes in real time and i want to call the fetch only when fetch data is changed from the previous already existing qty data

Comment: Yeah, but the dependency array specifies that the useEffect will be executed whenever you change the ```qty``` variable and then you change it inside the useEffect. Which will cause to constantly update

Comment: @szczocik, True, but in my case qty changes at times, and i want to only re render if the qty changes via fetch, is there a solution for that? Normally i refresh the page but i dont think this is an optimal option

Comment: so it changes regularly in the back end without the user interaction? In that case, you can do polling - fetch the data on regular intervals, says every 60 seconds. You could also look at websockets or similar technology, to allow back-end to send the updates when they happen and you will update the front-end in that case.

Comment: Or else, is there a way just to reload only that 1 component?, This component is a single part of my page. There are 2 operations that occur here, 1- The data changes in the backend without user interaction, 2-the data changes in the backend through another function that modifies the data in the frontend (this function must show the change in back end in real time)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making an infinite loop here because how you are setup the end of brackets `[qty]`

**render > useEffect > fetchData > [Qty](that mean data change) >re-render >useEfect > so on**

the most important part here is **the empty brackets []**

instead you can make a separate function like :

```
const fetchdata = () =>
{
fetch('/QtyCheck',{
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(qtyValue=>{
        setQty(qtyValue)
    })
}
useEffect(()=>{
fetchdata()
},[])`
```

Comment: Thankyou for the support @Salem_Raouf, but i want to fetch the data again if there is any changes to the qty, and i dont want it to render if there isn't any change. Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your state is an array. That means even when fetch returns the same content result it will have different reference. React won't look at deep level to compare, it does a shallow, and each array has different reference, hence multiples fetches. To solve you could pass to dependency array a stringified version `[JSON.stringify(qty)]` or do some conditional deep comparasion at your hook before sending the next request.

Regardless, it seems you also need an open channel between back and front, so everytime there is an update on back it sends back to front, since you say it changes from time to time at backend regardless frontend interaction. If that's the case you can use libs like socket.io to create this channel between back and front.